# How to get structured email headers from Outlook and process them in Power Automate Desktop

Tags: outlook, email-headers, power-automate-desktop

I am looking for a way to get structured email headers from Outlook and process them in Power Automate Desktop.

## Assumptions

You can retrieve email headers in Outlook by using the following URL
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-internet-message-headers-in-outlook-cd039382-dc6e-4264-ac74-c048563d212c

## The Challenge

The mail headers obtained from the client application Outlook are in text format and very difficult to handle.

## Constraints

We assume that we are parsing mail headers from an attached .msg file.
It is not possible to retrieve mail headers in json format using the Graph API.

Fortunately, Power Automate Desktop supports execution of VB script, JavaScript, Powershell, and DOS commands. It may be possible to take advantage of these to turn text into Json format, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Outlook Object Model in VBS, you can retrieve MIME headers from a received message by reading the `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS` MAPI property using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F")`